# Firebase emulator is not updating the cloud function document path but is updating the code within the function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

It's very weird. When I initially launch with firebase emulators:start with the below cloud function and make a change to one of the user documents it works as expected.

```js
exports.createPayment = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {
        const newValues = snap.after.data();
        console.log(newValues);
        console.log(context);
        const previousValues = snap.before.data();
        console.log(previousValues);
    });
```

Now here is where it get's weird. When I update the document specified from ('users/{userId}') to basically anything. It still only listens to ('users/{userId}') so I'm now at a point where my it looks like this

```js
exports.createPayment = functions.firestore.document('')
    .onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {
    ...
    });
```

This still TRIGGERS the onUpdate when I change something to a user. Now my first thought well the function isn't refreshing but here is where it gets EVEN weirder. When I add something between the brackets it does REFRESH that but still not the path so now my function looks like this:

```js
exports.createPayment = functions.firestore.document('')
    .onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {
        const newValues = snap.after.data();        
        console.log('this has just been added');
        console.log(newValues);
        console.log(context);
        const previousValues = snap.before.data();
        console.log(previousValues);


    });
```

It still listens to users/{userId} path, even though I have left it empty (or in other tests just put some gibberish there) but when I update something in the database it does now also         console.log 'this has just been added'. What the hell is going on here? It seems like the specified path isn't updating but the function is. Why is this?

Comment: If you have steps to reproduce something that looks like a bug in the Firebase emulator, post a bug report on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: This is my first time using firebase cloud functions and firebase emulator so I figured I'm doing something wrong and someone would point it out quickly but if that's not the case I will do as you say and create a bug report! Do you see anything strange about my code?